# Interrupt CSS transition by jquery event click and cancel reversing

Tags: css-transitions, interrupt

`.trans{
-webkit-transition:background-position 0.2s;
}`

I have nav menu items and added the transition above to each of them.

Also JQuery hover functions as:

`$(".menuUL li").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css({'background-position':'center top','color':'white'});});
            $(".menuUL li").mouseout(function () {

                if(this.id == currentTab)
                    {$(this).css({'background-position':'center top','color':'white'});}
                else
                    {$(this).css({'background-position':'center bottom','color':'#0196e3'});}});`

And click function to chance content:

`           $(".menuUL li").click(function(){

```
        $(".menuUL li").not(this).css({'background-position':'center bottom','background-color':'#666666','color':'#0196e3'});
        $(this).css({'background-position':'center top','background-color':'#CCCCCC','color':'white'});});
```

`

The problem is when I click on a menu item and suddenly(in <200ms) leave the element(mouseout) before the transition is completed. Reverse transition occurs and the clicked menu element's background position goes back to the initial position.

I need a code like $(this).endtransition()

Could you help pls?